# Cannot open terracotta 4.3.6 management console which is running on localhost:9540

Tags: caching, ehcache, terracotta

Terracotta server array is successfully running but the management console that comes with the Terracotta Server Open Source Software (OSS) kit is not working. when the terracotta server array is started ,it says  "2019-01-05 11:58:16,739 INFO - Management server started on 0.0.0.0:9540" but I get a not found error when I try to hit the url. Can anybody suggest how to view the caches stored inside terracotta or how can I access the management console?

According to "http://ww1.terracotta.org/documentation/4.1/tms/tms#enable-agent", management-console/bin/start-tmc.sh can be used to start the terracotta management console. But in the kit "TERRACOTTA SERVER 4.X AND OLDER" downloaded from "http://www.terracotta.org/open-source/" doesnt contain an file as start-tmc.sh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the way it works is that the Terracotta Server exposes REST endpoints via the built-in management server that's running on 0.0.0.0:9540 (hence why you see 2019-01-05 11:58:16,739 INFO - Management server started on 0.0.0.0:9540).

And then, you have the TMC (Terracotta Management Console) component that delivers the UI portion, and reaches back to the Terracotta management server to fetch the stats / data etc...

Now, the open-source version does not offer the Management Console...so that's why you don't see the "start-tmc.sh" in the kit.

But you should be able to access the REST endpoints from the built-in Terracotta Management Server anyway...

It should be accessible at: http://host:port/tc-management-api

And from there, you should be able to fetch all sort of data items using various REST calls (eg. /agents/topologies/ for the server topology, etc...)

Here is the latest doc for the Terracotta REST if you want to explore further:

https://documentation.softwareag.com/onlinehelp/Rohan/terracotta_436/bigmemory-max/webhelp/index.html#page/bigmemory-max-webhelp%2Fto-title_terracotta_rest_developer_guide.html%23

Finally, as explained in the doc (at https://documentation.softwareag.com/onlinehelp/Rohan/terracotta_436/bigmemory-max/webhelp/index.html#page/bigmemory-max-webhelp%2Fco-use_rest_api_versions.html%23), there are 2 API versions available...with the "v2" version being available and recommended for Terracotta 4.2 and higher (hence you should use the v2 with 4.3.6)

Lost of example REST calls at https://documentation.softwareag.com/onlinehelp/Rohan/terracotta_436/bigmemory-max/webhelp/index.html#page/bigmemory-max-webhelp%2Fco-oper_examples_of_uris.html%23... but couple here as well:

- curl http://localhost:9540/tc-management-api/v2/agents/info
- curl http://localhost:9540/tc-management-api/v2/agents/topologies/
- curl http://localhost:9540/tc-management-api/v2/agents/cacheManagers/

Hope that helps.

Comment: The terracotta is running in my system. When i try to hit http://localhost:9540/tc-management-api/ , i get 404 error. should i add anything to tc-config.xml or ehcache.xml configuration files to be able to access these TSA rest endpoints?

Comment: /tc-management-api is just the base url... adding the right resource call after that does yield responses... eg. curl http://localhost:9540/tc-management-api/v2/agents/topologies/ returns the current topology data, curl http://localhost:9540/tc-management-api/agents/cacheManagers/ returns the current cache managers, etc... Please refer to there doc link from my answer for more details on all the REST calls

Comment: I have explored the REST API and haven't found anything related to actually showing the data in each cache name. Is there a way of doing so?